# What does error in statement: ON or USING clause expected mean?

Tags: sql

I am very new to SQL and with help from this forum, I wrote the following SQL:

```
Select 
   Ekspeditioner.navn, Ekspeditioner.kundenr,
    Ekspeditioner.lbnr,
     Ekspeditioner.takserdato,
      Ekspliniersalg.ATCkode From ekspeditioner inner join  Ekspliniersalg where takserdato >=timestamp'2014-01-01 00:00:00' 
     and takserdato <=timestamp'2015-04-07 23:00:00'and Ekspliniersalg.atckode='N02BE01'
```

I get this error message:

> Error in statement: ON or USING clause expected.

I have tried this forum, a [SQL tutorial](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=18), Google and called the company who have made the software for the database I am working with and without any result.

Can anybody help me resolve this?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **[JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)** syntax is incorrect, you missing `ON`, should be like:

```
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name
```

Your code should be like:

```
SELECT Ekspeditioner.navn, 
       Ekspeditioner.kundenr,    
       Ekspeditioner.lbnr,
       Ekspeditioner.takserdato,
       Ekspliniersalg.ATCkode 
FROM  ekspeditioner 
JOIN  Ekspliniersalg 
-- Here should go ON
   ON ekspeditioner.column_name = Ekspliniersalg .column_name
WHERE takserdato >= timestamp'2014-01-01 00:00:00' 
      AND takserdato <=timestamp'2015-04-07 23:00:00'
      AND Ekspliniersalg.atckode='N02BE01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that we need ON clause for JOINS. The ON clause is used for making the relationship between joined tables. Note that the field used in ON clause are mostly primary keys or the combination of fields giving unique results except for cross join conditions.

Also better to use alias with table name.

So your query must be like this:

```
SELECT 
    A.navn, 
    A.kundenr,    
    A.lbnr,
    A.takserdato,
    B.ATCkode 
FROM  ekspeditioner  A
JOIN  Ekspliniersalg  B
-- use ON clause
   ON A.field_name = B .field_name
WHERE takserdato >= timestamp'2014-01-01 00:00:00'  --- use alias
      AND takserdato <=timestamp'2015-04-07 23:00:00'
      AND B.atckode='N02BE01';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! 
I have tried with alias but i think i did something wrong. it didn't work. That is the reason that i didn't do it. But shouldnt i write:

ekspeditioner as A ? or it dosent matter?

Comment: sure. please ask if you need any further help.

Comment: also use online sql formatter for formatting sql queries 
**http://sqlformat.org/**

Comment: Thank you again :) i am so glad that for the help from both of you.

Comment: user4221591 - thank you for the link, but i am not sure how to use it? should i opload my database first or how does it work?

Comment: just copy and paste the query and press FormatSQL

Comment: Please up-vote the answers and comments if they are useful to you. Thanks!

Comment: When mentioning aliases, at least I prefer to have such aliases that reminds me of original table names, like "ekspeditioner e" and, "Ekspliniersalg  es".

Comment: now i get it! very smart :) 

jarlh - sure your are both right about the use of alias -  makes it much more easy and simple to write the sql

Comment: i need more reputation points before i can upvote your answer :/